I want to include the API from weatherOpenMap in my website to show the weather dynamic icon based of that but it doesn't show up
I included this in my html header:
<script src="main.js"></script>

and this is in my weather section:
 <div class="weatherIcon"> 
            <h2><span id="weather-icon">weather icon...</span></h2> 
</div>

and this is in my JavaScript file (main.js):
const getWeather = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await  fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=gothenburg,se&APPID=c95f90301395e8ce1cb18d910cd184cb');
        const data = await response.json();
        const weatherCondition = data.weather[0].id;
        const weatherIcon = getWeatherIcon(weatherCondition);
       
        document.getElementById('weather-icon').innerHTML = weatherIcon;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error fetching weather data:',error);
    }


    
};
// Function to get the appropriate weather icon based on the weather condition code
const getWeatherIcon = (weatherCondition) => {
    if (weatherCondition >= 200 && weatherCondition < 300) {
        return '<i class="wi wi-thunderstorm weather-icon"></i>'; // Thunderstorm
    } else if (weatherCondition >= 300 && weatherCondition < 400) {
        return '<i class="wi wi-rain weather-icon"></i>'; // Drizzle
    } else if (weatherCondition >= 500 && weatherCondition < 600) {
        return '<i class="wi wi-day-rain weather-icon"></i>'; // Rain
    } else if (weatherCondition >= 600 && weatherCondition < 700) {
        return '<i class="wi wi-day-snow weather-icon"></i>'; // Snow
    } else if (weatherCondition >= 700 && weatherCondition < 800) {
        return '<i class="wi wi-fog weather-icon"></i>'; // Atmosphere
    } else if (weatherCondition === 800) {
        return '<i class="wi wi-day-sunny weather-icon"></i>'; // Clear
    } else if (weatherCondition > 800) {
        return '<i class="wi wi-day-cloudy weather-icon"></i>'; // Clouds
    } else {
        return '';
    }
};

// Call the getWeather function to fetch weather data and display the icon
getWeather();

and this is in style.css:
.weatherIcon {
    font-size: 2em;
}

Now when I open my index.html in browser, it shows the text (weather icon ...) so I am guessing the files are connected correctly, and when I search the API in browser it give me a data, so I don't know what is the problem, does anyone have any idea?

I think you missing weather-icon style in your HTML.
All other codes are fine.
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Weather Icon Display</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/weather-icons/2.0.12/css/weather-icons.min.css">
    <style>
        .weatherIcon {
            font-size: 2em;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 20px;
            color: #0056b3;
        }
        .weatherIcon i {
            color: #00468b;
            text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="weatherIcon"> 
        <h2><span id="weather-icon">weather icon...</span></h2> 
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

main.js
const getWeather = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await  fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=gothenburg,se&APPID=c95f90301395e8ce1cb18d910cd184cb');
        const data = await response.json();
        const weatherCondition = data.weather[0].id;
        const weatherIcon = getWeatherIcon(weatherCondition);
       
        document.getElementById('weather-icon').innerHTML = weatherIcon;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error fetching weather data:',error);
        document.getElementById('weather-icon').innerHTML = '<i class="wi wi-na"></i>'; // Default icon on error
    }    
};
// Function to get the appropriate weather icon based on the weather condition code
const getWeatherIcon = (weatherCondition) => {
    if (weatherCondition >= 200 && weatherCondition < 300) {
        return '<i class="wi wi-thunderstorm weather-icon"></i>'; // Thunderstorm
    } else if (weatherCondition >= 300 && weatherCondition < 400) {
        return '<i class="wi wi-rain weather-icon"></i>'; // Drizzle
    } else if (weatherCondition >= 500 && weatherCondition < 600) {
        return '<i class="wi wi-day-rain weather-icon"></i>'; // Rain
    } else if (weatherCondition >= 600 && weatherCondition < 700) {
        return '<i class="wi wi-day-snow weather-icon"></i>'; // Snow
    } else if (weatherCondition >= 700 && weatherCondition < 800) {
        return '<i class="wi wi-fog weather-icon"></i>'; // Atmosphere
    } else if (weatherCondition === 800) {
        return '<i class="wi wi-day-sunny weather-icon"></i>'; // Clear
    } else if (weatherCondition > 800) {
        return '<i class="wi wi-day-cloudy weather-icon"></i>'; // Clouds
    } else {
        return '';
    }
};

// Call the getWeather function to fetch weather data and display the icon
getWeather();

Result


omg thank youuu, you are a lifesaver. I tried this and it show the result you mentioned. but still when I do it with the rest of the codes in my project it still doesn't show it, do you think it might be because of my ordering? do you have any suggestion or tips for ordering? like do they have to be in a same order in main.js that I wrote them in index.html

Try this code, replace getWeather(); to document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getWeather);
